I have dead grass near newly laid concrete
I recently had a new walkway with a broom finish install at the front of my house.  Within a couple days I noticed an area of grass was dead.  Could this be due to spilling some of the sealer on my grass??  If not, what else from this install could be killing my grass.

Pictures ?  .....

The reason this might be due to concrete falling on grass that leads to alkalinity of the soil which means the pH level of soil reaches to <7 and it results in grass death.
Another reason, that could happen is that maybe any chemical residues or sealer may fall on grass or soil which can also lead to clearing grass in an area.
If you want grass over there the solution is to replant the affected area after properly clearing the area.
